# Evento on('change') dispara ao clicar fora do elemento

Tags: jquery

Tenho o seguinte código em um `input` do *type* `file`:

```
$('input-imagem').on('change', function() {
   alert( $(this).val()); 
});
```

Funciona quase certinho, quando eu clico fora do `input` ele dá o `alert` novamente e isso não deveria ocorrer, deveria dar o `alert` somente quando eu escolho uma imagem.

Comment: O que é o `input-imagem`? um select? Já agora falta um `#` ou `.` aqui : `$('input-imagem')`

Comment: Ele colocou @Sergio é type file !!!

Answer (score 2):

**Faça assim:**

Faltou você definir **.** para **class** ou **#** para o **id** do elemento do tipo *input file*

```
<input type="file" name="input-imagem" id="input-imagem" >
```

---

```
$('#input-imagem').change(function() {
   if ($(this).val() != ""){
      alert($(this).val()); 
   }
});
```

***Exemplo:*** [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bruxohpotter/uLCYL/)

ou

```
$('#input-imagem').on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).val() != ""){
       alert( $(this).val());
    }
});
```

***Exemplo:*** [**fiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/bruxohpotter/4M25z/)